# C# -Excel interoperability

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I want to call Excel Sheet from C# 4.0 (VS 2010 Express Edition) .

When i declare ,

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel =
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

excel.Visible = true;
```

I receive error as

*Interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.*

What is the soultion ?

Answer (score 35):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx) is a blog post that deals with that.  Looks like you need to change

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

to

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer for me was to mark Embed Interop types as false. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded) question.

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

`Excel.ApplicationClass` derives from `Excel.Application` interface and one can even instantiate Excel using `Excel.Application` interface. 
Rewriting this code as below produces exact same results:

```
Excel.Application xlapp = new Excel.Application();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`, but instantiate it as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Excel.Application = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

Note the leading `Excel.Application`, not `Excel.ApplicationClass`.

Also note, this is straight out of the [MSDN page for ApplicationClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass%28office.11%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For MS Office 2016 you need to use the following no dramas

```
Excel.Application oExcel = new Excel.Application();
```