# Access COM dynamicaly from C#

Tags: c#, com

I am trying to access COM object from on the fly compiled C# code.

It's impossible to add assembly reference and "use" it by regular way, can anybody point me to dynamical COM query example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use System.Activator to load the COM object on the fly, for example:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("CDO.Message");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

And use `Type.InvokeMember()` to call the methods of the object.

Comment: Exactly what I need, and it's called Late Binding, now I know ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know this will work for Office COM Interop, not sure about any other libraries.

I Hope you do mean you want to use the new `dynamic` type with C#?

You need to use .NET4 no Pia feature:

1. Add a COM reference, Right click it.
2. Click properties.
3. And there should be the option there -> Embed Interop Assembly.
   Make sure its TRUE.

Now, if you notice, most of the constructors and methods will have optional arguments, and certain objects (like worksheets I think) will be of type `dynamic`.

If you do have a `"Interop Type cannot be embedded error"` See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded/4553402#4553402)