# Can NuGet distribute a COM dll?

Tags: visual-studio, com, nuget

Is it possible to use NuGet to distribute a COM DLL?

How would I setup the package?

I'm thinking that I could put the DLL in the Tools directory, then run a post-install script to register the library, but I'm not very good at PowerShell.

Are there any online examples of how to do this (if its possible)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When I faced a similar problem I created a NuGet package with the following structure.

- lib

  - MYCOMLib.dll
- tools

  - mycom.dll
  - install.ps1

The MYCOMLib.dll is a interop DLL generated from the mycom.dll with the [Type Library Importer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (tlbimp.exe).
This is simply done with the command :

```
Tlbimp mycom.dll
```

The install.ps1 contains the following code:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

regsvr32 Join-Path $toolsPath '\mycom.dll' /s

$project.Object.References | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "MYCOMLib" } |  ForEach-Object { $_.EmbedInteropTypes = $false }
```

What this script does is that it registers the COM dll and sets the EmbedInteropTypes property on the reference to false, which is necessary when using .NET 4. See [Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded) for more information.

Comment: I wish I could also accept your answer. This did help, really.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question to ask, but do I need to manually run the install.ps1 PS script in order for it to take effect, or is it automatically ran by the NuGet installation process?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller nuget will run it during its install process if you place the install.ps1 in a tools folder in your nupkg.

Comment: It appears the PowerShell install and uninstall scripts are no longer supported since NuGet 3
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/NuGet-3-What-and-Why/#powershell-install-and-uninstall-scripts