# How to register a COM shared as a NuGet Package in a Class Library (.NET Core)?

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget, .net-core-rc2, .net-standard-1.5

There are 4 projects:

1. MyProject.Domain
2. MyProject.Services.Contracts
3. MyProject.Services.Acomba
4. MyProject.Services.Acomba.Tests

The Acomba projects depends on a NuGet Package that I packed according to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203098/162167).

All of those projects are of type [Class Library (.NET Core)](http://dotnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts/class-libraries.html) and target:

- NET451
- NET452
- NET461
- NETSTANDARD1.5

Except for the test project which consists of a .NET Core App which target:

- NETCOREAPP1.0

As the [Getting started with xUnit.net (.NET Core / ASP.NET Core)](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html#add-xunit-ref) webpage describes.

Whether I run the tests from the [console](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html#run-tests-console) or [Visual Studio](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core.html#run-tests-vs), it ends up with this error:

> *System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000115-0000-000F-1000-000AC0BA1001} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLA
>   SSNOTREG))*.

This message makes it obvious that the COM library on which depends the Acomba projects is not registered on my local workstation, although I went through the installation process of the SDK shared as a COM library.

So my wish would be to run this **install.ps1** Powershell Script from the NuGet Package or to get it ran automatically on project compile. Unfortunately, this script is nowhere to be found, neither are the packages referenced in my projects, since their compiled on the fly with [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform).

**How to register a COM shared as such through a Nuget Package in a Class Library (.NET Core)?**

**UPDATE**

Based on this post: [Creating a Nuget package that will install files relative to the solution](http://www.vicesoftware.com/nuget/creating-a-nuget-package-that-will-install-files-relative-to-the-solution/), the **install.ps1** script contained in the **tools** folder of the NuGet Package should be run upon Package installation. So I guess this might be something about the script itself that doesn't really work out.

**Is there anything wrong with this script?**

I don't know much about Powershell, hence my question.

**install.ps1**

```
param( $installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project )

regsvr32 Join-Path $toolsPath '\AcoSDK.dll' /s

$project.Object.References 
    | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Acomba.SDK" } 
    | ForEach-Object { $_.EmbedInteropTypes = $false }
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed whilst registering the DLL using `regsvr32.exe` that there was an error. It turned out to require elevated permissions to register the DLL. So, I tried running VS as an admin, and it changed nothing. The same error message displays. =(

Can it be because I run tests using a NETCOREAPP1.0 (test project) with a NETSTANDARD1.5 library that it fails or?

To be noticed that whenever I use a "regular" Class Library, it works flawlessly. I just don't understand the problem...

**UPDATE**

The CLSID is found in the Windows Registry using RegEdit.exe. So it is registered.

**What could cause the project not to find the registration or whatever it is?**

Comment: Just a wild guess: might it be related to the bitness of your COM component (32bit/64bit)?

Comment: @DavidBrabant: I just can't say. I guess the COM library is 32 bits, due to the project debut which is many, many years ago. I heard there would be a conflict about the architecture registering with either version of `regsvr32.exe` - I just can't remember which is which.

Comment: @DavidBrabant: After some findings, I registered the COM using both regsvr32, and the issue persists. I tried to find how to target x86 CPU architecture in my XPROJ (Class Library (.NET Core)). The only option available is `AnyCPU`, which seems to cause some problem on a 64bit Windows like mine. I created a new compile configuration option which is `x86`, and it didn't seem to solve the problem - except that I created it from `AnyCPU`, since `x86` doesn't seem to exist in a XPROJ, neither the advanced configuration options.