# How to target x86 platform in a XPROJ?

Tags: .net, com, x86-64

I have this issue:

[**`How to register a COM shared as a NuGet Package in a Class Library (.NET Core)?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365362/how-to-register-a-com-shared-as-a-nuget-package-in-a-class-library-net-core)

Which solution seems to be:

- [**`Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892577/162167)
- [**`Visual Basic.Net error 80040154`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDtyGns6mOw)

But when I go to the XPROJ project properties, there ain't any Advanced Configuration Options, neither is a target platform found.

1. **How to target x86 platform using a XPROJ?**
2. **Is it only doable?**

My goal is to fully take advantage of the `project.json` file and this NuGet Package restore feature instead of using the old-fashioned references to DLL directly.

Comment: It makes *very* little sense to try to do this in a .NETCore project, it ain't ever going to run on Linux or OSX.  Did I say that before?  Options are very restricted, keep on eye [on this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8654).

Comment: @HansPassant: You're right. I have been confused with all the new features and project types there are now in the VS Project Templates. So my guess is that the best choice to fully take advantage of the new features such as NuGet Package references would then be Portable Class Library, for what I wish to achieve, here - right?