# The template parameter in InitializeFromPrivateKey() on CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 object causes exception when trying a specific Template

Tags: javascript, templates, certificate, certificate-authority, certenroll

I am having an issue with specifying the template parameter in *InitializeFromPrivateKey()* on the *X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10* object. Anything other than a template of *"User"* is resulting in the following exception:-

**CertEnroll::CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10::InitializeFromPrivateKey: The requested certificate template is not supported by this CA. 0x80094800 (-2146875392)**

There is a specific Certificate template that I need to be used, and when I try it then the code throws the exception. The template exists on the CA, and on the client machine which is running the following code.

Javascript code as follows:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     var sCertificate = null;
     var sDistinguishedName = "C=\"\";S=\"\";L=\"\";O=\"XXXXX\";OU=\"XXXXXXX\";E=\"XXXXX@XXXX.com\";CN=\"xxxxxxx\";";
     var template = "RegistrationCert"; //Anything Other than "User" fails, have tried template Oid too.

     var classFactory = new ActiveXObject("X509Enrollment.CX509EnrollmentWebClassFactory");
     var objEnroll = classFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment");
     var objPrivateKey = classFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey");
     var objRequest = classFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10");
     var objDN = classFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX500DistinguishedName");

     objPrivateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
     objPrivateKey.KeySpec = "1";
     objPrivateKey.ProviderType = "1";

    try 
    {
            objRequest.InitializeFromPrivateKey(1, objPrivateKey, template);
            objDN.Encode(sDistinguishedName, 0);
            objRequest.Subject = objDN;
            objEnroll.InitializeFromRequest(objRequest);
            sCertificate = objEnroll.CreateRequest(1);
            document.writeln(sCertificate);
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
             document.writeln(ex.description);
    }
 </script>
```

**Couple of other questions**
- I assume that the template should exist on the Client Machine? Otherwise how does it know the location of the CA to query for templates?
- Does CertEnroll on a Client even work against a Windows 2003 CA server??

If you can help me that it would be much appreciated!!!

**Additional Info**
- Client is Windows 7, with MS IE9 Client running as Administrator.
- Web App which hosts the above page is accessed over HTTPs.
- Web App is hosted on a Win2003 CA Server.

**Before posting I have looked at...**
- Stackoverflow threads regarding CertEnroll + InitializeFromPrivateKey
- [Blogs about using Template OID not Template name](http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2010/04/the-ix509certificaterequestpkcs10-initializefromtemplatename-adventure/)
- [MSDN / alejacma's Site](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/tags/certenroll/)
- CertEnroll API on MSDN

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so figured it..typical.

- Use *CX509ExtensionTemplateName*, and call *InitializeEncode* with the **OID** template value
- Don't specify a template param in *InitializeFromPrivateKey*.

i.e:

```
var objExtensionTemplate = classFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509ExtensionTemplateName")


objRequest.InitializeFromPrivateKey(1, objPrivateKey, ""); //empty string, don't specify template here
objExtensionTemplate.InitializeEncode(template); //Specify Template as OID value!
objRequest.X509Extensions.Add(objExtensionTemplate);
```

Have verified on the CA that the request is for the template type I specified, and does indeed only create a cert for that type.

Hope this helps somebody one day.

Comment: +1 for coming back and telling us that you got it fixed and how you did it. You're using SO right!

Answer (score 1):

See also this code, where I'm using a newer DLL that doesn't include the methods you're using.  I also am not using the ["interop types"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2483659/328397) which cause issues when deploying or building the code.

```
 CObjectId EkuOid = new CObjectId();
        EkuOid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.4946465.16405226.12930948.10533807.2139545.33.5005369.11644649");
        CObjectIds EkuOids = new CObjectIds();
        EkuOids.Add(EkuOid);
        CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
        eku.InitializeEncode(EkuOids);
        eku.Critical = false;
        objPkcs10.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)eku);
```

The OID can be obtained using [this method on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/610024/51457)

Alternate implementations of this code (VBS, C#, etc) [is located here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182332(v=ws.10).aspx)