# Embed Interop Types to false that Does Not Work

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, office-interop

I am using Office references in project, actually Excel references. However I have compile issues like this one -> [Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)

I  set the Embed Interop Types to false. However it does not work, compiler still gives the errors like the same above.

This problem appeared because: I completed this project some months ago. People were using it however they want some extras. The time when I built the project completely, Office 2007 was installed on my PC. Now, I have Office 2010. so I think the main reason is this.
Thank you.