# C# Windows session connection event

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

Is there any event to be used by process on local or remote session connection?

I need to wait for user to login, and then execute some action.

I know that it is possible to monitor Security event log for login event.

Is there a direct way of achieving this?

Comment: can you be more clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried please

Comment: Execute something on user connection (login). Not by looping and checking the eventlog, but to get the trigger from OS.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution.
As I'm creating a service - it is quite easy.
[Get notified from logon and logoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282231/get-notified-from-logon-and-logoff)