# C# WndProc in Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, service

I have created a C# Windows Form that uses WTSRegisterSessionNotification to Register for Remote Desktop session notifications. Then I am handling the WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE message in WndProc callback function. The issue I am having is that I want to achieve the same functionality as a Windows Service.

When I tried the following in a Windows Service project Result = False.

```
var result = WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, 1);
```

So I cant even register the notification. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Services run in their own world, in session 0.  No interactive users run in session 0.  WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE is a window message (i.e., something a window receives).  Services don't have windows.  That message is also about a change in the session - which is necessarily a different session that what the service is running in.  What you are trying to do will not work (as far as I know).  So...  What do you really want to do?  Be notified when a user logs in or out?  Something else?  There may be a way to do what you wan that will work.

Comment: I need a way to be notified that a user logs in and out.

Comment: This seems harder than I thought it would be... Try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282231/get-notified-from-logon-and-logoff