# Log Parser c# error using STRCAT with CASE

Tags: case, strcat, logparser

I'm having trouble with the log parser, punctually on the use of the function STRCAT parameter  with CASE, using log parser the query works perfectly and using a simple STRCAT without CASE  the query works even using c#, the problem starts when i use CASE. Am I missing something?

Here's the error:
CLogQueryClass: Error 8007064f: Execute: error parsing query: Syntax Error: : cannot find closing parenthesys for function STRCAT [ SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported. ]

```
string query = "SELECT " + " STRCAT('" + entry.Name +"'";
                query += @", CASE INDEX_OF(SUBSTR(cs-uri-stem,1), '/')
                            WHEN 'NULL' THEN 'DEFAULTAPPPOOL'
                            ELSE EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs-uri-stem,1,'/')
                            END";
                query += ") AS APPPOOL";
                query += ", '" + Environment.MachineName + "' as server";
                query += ", '" + entry.Name + "' as site";
                query += ", cs-uri-stem as csUriStem";
                query += ", c-ip as cIp, sc-status as scStatus";
                query += ", sc-bytes as scBytes";
                query += ", cs-bytes as csBytes";
                query += ", time-taken as timeTaken";
                query += " FROM " + logAddress + "\\" + yesterdayLogName;
                // Initialize a LogQuery object
                logQuery = new LogQueryClass();
                logRecordSet = logQuery.Execute(query,new COMIISW3CInputContextClass());

                //SHOWS RESULT
                for (; !logRecordSet.atEnd(); logRecordSet.moveNext())
                {
                    logrecord = logRecordSet.getRecord();
                    int i = 0;
                    while (i < 9)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(logrecord.getValue(i));
                        i++;
                    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Filter the title through `tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`, all-caps is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like you are mixing types. The `CASE INDEX_OF(SUBSTR(cs-uri-stem,1), '/') WHEN 'NULL'` compares an integer to string. This should be:

```
CASE INDEX_OF(SUBSTR(cs-uri-stem,1), '/') 
   WHEN NULL THEN 'DEFAULTAPPPOOL'
   ELSE EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs-uri-stem,1,'/')
END
```

The error complains about finding the close parenthesis, but I've found that parsing errors can result in misleading error messages with LogParser.

Second, I've tested the following in C# targeted at .NET 3.5 (4.0 had an issue with embedded type. [Similar to this...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)):

```
string logAddress = "C:\\Path\\to\\consolidatedFile";
string entryName = "blah";
string yesterdayLogName = "fileName.log";

string query = "SELECT " + " STRCAT('" + entryName + "'"
                + ", CASE INDEX_OF(SUBSTR(cs-uri-stem,1), '/') "
                    + "WHEN NULL THEN 'DEFAULTAPPPOOL' "
                    + "ELSE EXTRACT_TOKEN(cs-uri-stem,1,'/') "
                + "END"
             + ") AS APPPOOL"
             + ", '" + Environment.MachineName + "' as server"
             + ", '" + entryName + "' as site"
             + ", cs-uri-stem as csUriStem"
             + ", c-ip as cIp, sc-status as scStatus"
             + ", sc-bytes as scBytes"
             + ", cs-bytes as csBytes"
             + ", time-taken as timeTaken"
             + " FROM " + logAddress + "\\" + yesterdayLogName;

// Initialize a LogQuery object
COMW3CInputContextClassClass ctx = new COMW3CInputContextClassClass();
//LogQueryClass logQuery = new LogQueryClass();
LogQueryClass logQuery = new LogQueryClassClass();
//ILogRecordset logRecordSet = logQuery.Execute(query, new COMIISW3CInputContextClass());
ILogRecordset logRecordSet = logQuery.Execute(query, ctx);

//SHOWS RESULT
for (; !logRecordSet.atEnd(); logRecordSet.moveNext())
{
    ILogRecord logrecord = logRecordSet.getRecord();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(logrecord.getValue(i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

This ran successfully and return results. I commented out the lines initially presented since when I used them nothing returned on the console. That might be a difference of the code not presented. Finally, I substituted a string `entryName` for the `entry.Name` object assuming that it returns a string.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Does your compiled query run from the LogParser commandline tool? I would recommend starting there and working backwards. Also, did the error end up changing at all or are you still getting the exact same one?

Comment: @nathansantanna See the above edits. I have now successfully tested in C#.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, i tried your solution again i copied the query and changed the strings values, and i'm still getting the same error with closing parenthesys. Thankf for the help im getting crazy with this error

Comment: @nathansantanna What version of the LogParser dll are you using? This was against 2.2.10. If you copied exactly as is, you must have an invalid character or a character that is opening up some part of the syntax in one of your variables then. What is in `entry.Name`?

Comment: yes i'm using log parser 2.2.10, entry name is just the web site "id" on iis, anyway i substituted all variables for a simple string too :/. thanks for the efforts

Comment: got it, i tried the software in another server and worked perfectly, thanks for your help