# Unable to cast COM object of type 'microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to 'microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'"

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

I am attempting to capture some data from Excel from within a C# console application.

I get the error

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to 'microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'"

This code used the 'Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library', and I included a reference to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'.

I dug a little bit this site and came across
*[Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)*, but I could not understand it enough to implement what was suggested as a solution.

My .NET version is 4.5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace deneme
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true; // <-- excel application
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

        // Open the workbook.
        Excel.Workbook wBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\FNN\\XLA\\fnnComTemplate.xlsx",
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

        // get the sheet
        Excel.Worksheet wSheet = wBook.Sheets[0];
        // foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in wBook.Sheets) { if (sheet.Name == "templateSheet") { wSheet = sheet; } }

        Excel.Range rng = wSheet.get_Range("A1");

        aux = wSheet.Range["F6"].Value;

        Console.WriteLine("interop result:" + aux);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-of

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dau-blog/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application.aspx).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If this is not a code-related error, then please remove the registry key listed below. This issue is caused by the key being left over from a higher version of Office.

Steps:

1. Go to Start
2. Select Run
3. Type regedit and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> TypeLib -> {00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} -> 1.9/1.8/1.7
5. Delete the registry key

Comment: Please explain what problem you perceived from OP's question, what deleting this registry key does, why you think that will solve OP's problem and where you found this solution.

Comment: In case you have Office2016 and unable to get interop to work you need tzo install Off2013. The you need to delete this reg. key to get office interop to work.
In case you don't have office interop instal nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/

Comment: Old question, I know but: Cool! You just saved us a lot of time! Just to add, this also might happen when you move from 64 bit to 32 bit. This works because apparently the office interop is trying to use the highest version and/or 64 bit if available. If there is a path in this key that does not exist, it will give this error. So if the office version is uninstalled but the key is still there, it fails when looking up the path!

Comment: Thank you rperz86.  That was it for me.  I had switched from 64 to 32 bits for an app that was going to be used on some old computers and I thought 32 bit would be the safe option.  So yeah, adding comments to old posts does help.  Thanks

Answer (score 80):

### For Microsoft Office 365 in Windows 10

I was running Microsoft Office 365 with Windows 10 and tried the mentioned solutions to remove the registry key without success.

I went to **Settings -> Apps** in an attempt to repair the Office 365 suite:

[image: Screenshot of the Microsoft Office 365 entry in Apps & features in the Windows 10+ Settings menu, with the mouse hovering over/clicking on the "Modify" button]

To get there you can follow these steps:

1. Open Start
2. Select Settings
3. Select Apps
4. In the default page, Apps & features, search for Microsoft 365
5. Select "Microsoft 365"
6. Select "Modify"

I selected the Quick Repair option:

[image: Screenshot of the Office Modify wizard with the 'Quick Repair' option selected]

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: The quick repair helped me (but it was at least 5 minutes). Make sure you look for "Microsoft 365 Apps" in "Add or remove programs" and not for "Office", else you will repair the wrong office. 

Originally I installed office365 while keeping the old office. At one point the windows started to use the old office, I set again to use the new one, but then I had this error.

Comment: I kept repairing an Application named  "Microsoft 365 (Office)" and it was doing nothing.  I finally slowed down and looked again and there is also an app named "Microsoft Office 365 -en-us.  Doing a repair here did take a few minutes but resolved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

A simple **repair of Microsoft Office** resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I've done this and it work !

Answer (score 3):

Using the exact same code I got the same problem in a laptop when everything worked fine on another one. I tried various solutions found here and there in the internet but what finally worked, was the explicit definition of the use of non 32 bit version of the library. For doing so in visual studio, I had to tick and then untick the box "Prefer 32-bit" in the build section of the project configuration, which added `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 2):

A machine had been updated to Office 2016 64-bit and the COM interface was throwing exceptions when called from the a 32-bit application. It did not have old TypeLib entries like the ones in Jayesh's answer.

Comparing ProcessMonitor traces to a working machine with Office 2016 led to what look like dead end registry keys in

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{00024..

The working machine would check for the non-existent registry key and return

> NAME NOT FOUND

The failing machine had the registry key but then would throw an exception shortly thereafter.

After repeatedly deleting the registry key, rerunning the trace, deleting the next failing key, the COM interface functionality was restored.

Answer (score 2):

My setup: *Visual Studio: 2019, Office: 2019 x64, Target Framework: net5.0-windows*

Nothing help me from error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

So I found via Sysinternals Process Monitor a missing file path for `Excel.exe` in the Registry for Win32 and changed it to the existing x64 version:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\1.9\0\win32]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in PowerShell. Along with the mentioned issue, `$xlApp.Workbooks` returned null for me. Running the PowerShell script in 32-bit mode resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Start->Run->Regedit
find this path
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
and remove it
and repair your office packet

Answer (score 0):

In my case
I delete regedit in:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`

delete 1.9
[image]

and problem solved.

Comment: This appears to repeat the accepted answer from 2015 by Jayesh Goyani.