# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

I've got a C# Application which I'm using to convert .txt files to .xlsx. While doing the conversion I am getting an error thrown "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

2. Windows 10 64 Bit
3. Microsoft Office 365

The application was fully functional prior to updates pushed to the PC. Previous issues have been old registry keys and missing drivers.

I can't find much on this specific error, any ideas?

Comment: Please tag properly .. from exception looks like the file you are trying to read/convert is not present in the path you are looking for anymore

Comment: @Rahul Thank you Rahul! The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066719/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationcla I needed to preform a repair.

Answer (score 0):

The fix can be found in the second solution listed here: [unable to cast COM object of type 'microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to 'microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066719/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationcla)

A simple repair is all that was needed. No need to chase anything down!