# Unity - How to RegisterType for a COM Interop DLL

Tags: c#, com, interop, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have an old COM Interop dll that I have to include in my .Net 4.5.1 application. The application uses Unity for IoC and DI.

The Interop dll has the following, simplified:

```
public interface ILegacyInterop
{
    void DoStuff()
}

public interface LegacyInterop : ILegacyInterop
{
}

public class LegacyInteropClass : ILegacyInterop, LegacyInterop 
{
    public LegacyInteropClass();

    public virtual void DoStuff();
}
```

I have tried the following to wire up the interface as follows

```
container.RegisterType<ILegacyInterop, LegacyInterop>();
```

and

```
container.RegisterType<ILegacyInterop, LegacyInteropClass>();
```

and

```
container.RegisterType<LegacyInterop, LegacyInteropClass>();
```

None of which work.

The first option gives the following error on run:

> InvalidOperationException - The current type, LegacyInterop, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

The second and third options give the following error on build:

> Interop type 'LegacyInteropClass' cannot be embedded. Use the
>   applicable interface instead.

Is what I am trying to do actually possible? If so, how?

I can get the interop to work by instantiating `LegacyInterop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out with the help of [Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)

The offending Interop reference needs **Embed Interop Assembly** set to **False**

Then `container.RegisterType<ILegacyInterop, LegacyInteropClass>();` works