# C# Access reports printing code error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access

I am trying to pull and send a report to a printer.
I found this   but i get these odd object type errors. I think that I am using this wrong. sorry for the noob question but if i could get some help that would be solid .

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        DoCmd.OpenReport("Sales", //ReportName
                          objAccApp.AcView.acViewPreview, //View
                          System.Reflection.Missing.Value, //FilterName
                          System.Reflection.Missing.Value //WhereCondition);
}
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0103  The name
>   'DoCmd' does not exist in the current
>   context   AllianceERP C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\AllianceERP\AllianceERP\Form1.cs 1033
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0103  The name
>   'AcView' does not exist in the current
>   context   AllianceERP C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\AllianceERP\AllianceERP\Form1.cs 1035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DoCmd.OpenReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx) is a VBA method and it can't be used directly in C#.

Try using [Access Office Interop Objects](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317114):

```
Access.Application oAccess = null;

// Start a new instance of Access for Automation:
oAccess = new Access.ApplicationClass();

// Open a database in exclusive mode:
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(
   "c:\\mydb.mdb", //filepath
   true //Exclusive
   );

// Preview a report named Sales:
oAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport(
   "Sales", //ReportName
   Access.AcView.acViewPreview, //View
   System.Reflection.Missing.Value, //FilterName
   System.Reflection.Missing.Value //WhereCondition
   );
```

Comment: i used your code updated my                                                                      using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access; but i get thies error Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1752 Interop type 'ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead. AllianceERP C:\Users\dhelm.ALLMATINC.001\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AllianceERP\AllianceERP\Form1.cs 1040

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded