# “Interop type cannot be embedded” issue when exporting activeview to PNG file using Arcobject

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, esri, arcobjects

This maybe a very silly question but it bothers me quite a while. When I tried to export Activeview of ArcMap to a PNG file using the "IExport" interface from Arcobjects C#. Visual Studio always pops out this error message:[screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8hZx.png)

```
IExport export= new ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.ExportPNGClass();
```

Error: Interop type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.ExportPNGClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

I am not sure why the "ExportPNGClass" cannot be embedded or why is "IExport" is not an applicable interface. The ESRI [example](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#6a92027b-31ee-4a10-b3c3-08272842e9c1.htm) is also using the same interface and coclass to export maps.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and Visual Studio 2012 with .Net framework 4.0.  Following references were added in front of the code:

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Output;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I assume the setting `Embed Interop Type` for the assembly which contains the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` is set to true. Try setting it to false.

Comment: see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553402/2592875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553402/2592875) for a similar issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)

Comment: @NtFreX, Thx! That solves my issue！

Comment: @ Jasper Schellingerhout, yes, very similar.  Only contribution might be: need to check ALL Interop settings.