# Runtime error while opening a windows form of a .net 4.5 project from .net 2.0 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, .net-2.0

I have two .net projects in my solution.First project is .net 2.0 windows forms project and the second project is .net 4.5 windows forms project.I'm opening a windows form of my .net 4.5 project from .net 2.0 project. for code example:

```
    ReportManager.Form1 f1 = new ReportManager.Form1();
    f1.Show();
```

it gives following run time error (ReportManager is my .net 4.5 project name)

Could not load file or assembly 'ReportManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
any advice is welcome.

Comment: How are you getting it to compile? Or are you trying to explicitly load the .net 4.5 assembly at runtime?

Comment: this errors came just when I'm compiling the solutions after several clean an bild attempts now deferment error is coming "The thread 0x1a3c has exited with code 259 (0x103)."

Comment: OK, so it's specifically *not* a "run time error". A .NET 2.0 project won't compile against more recent dependencies. Can you not migrate your project forward?

Comment: No I can't because my .NET 2.0 project is using some SDK which only supports for .NET 2.0

Comment: Your project, built against .NET 4.5, should still be able to make use of a .NET 2.0 SDK (and your ReportManager too), though?

Comment: Did try to convert and build my .NET 2.0 project and this error came "Interop type 'LOGkeeper.ManagerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment "Did try to convert and build my .NET 2.0 project and this error came "Interop type 'LOGkeeper.ManagerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead."

Perhaps this helps in migrating the project up from .NET 2.0?

[Interop type cannot be embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483659/interop-type-cannot-be-embedded)

Comment: Thanks, It worked Julia Hayward. I just convert my .NET 2.0 project to .NET 4.5 and on the reference section right clicked on my .NET 2.0 SDK library and select properties then there was a key named "Embed Interop Types". I just did set it to "false" and now every thing works fine.